# Centering divs with display inline-block causes spacing below rows

Tags: html, css

In the following example I am trying to create a div that contains any number of other divs which are centered and contain four divs per row (with the last row containing however many are left if the total number of images is not divisible by four).

However, it's causing there to be a small (about 3 pixels) spacing below each row of images. Is there any way to make the images so they have no spacing above/below each row?

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
  text-align: center;
}
.image {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25%;
}
.image img {
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <a href="#" class="image">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/400x400" alt="">
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="image">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/400x400" alt="">
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="image">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/400x400" alt="">
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="image">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/400x400" alt="">
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="image">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/400x400" alt="">
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="image">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/400x400" alt="">
  </a>
</div>
```

Just for good measure, here's a screenshot showing the gap I'm referring to:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix this by adding `vertical-align: top;` to your images.

**CSS**

```
.image img {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
  text-align: center;
}
.image {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25%;
}
.image img {
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <a href="#" class="image">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/400x400" alt="">
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="image">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/400x400" alt="">
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="image">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/400x400" alt="">
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="image">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/400x400" alt="">
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="image">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/400x400" alt="">
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="image">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/400x400" alt="">
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Browser automatically adds some space between lines of (what it considers) text. You can resolve it simply by adding `font-size: 0` to the images' wrapper.

Comment: This is also helpful. While the accepted answer of adding `vertical-align: top` to the `.image img` selector does remove the margin below each image, I later noticed that there were also margins on the left and right in Firefox. Adding `font-size: 0` to both the `.container` and `.image img` selectors seems to resolve this issue for me.

Comment: Yes, these gaps aren't limited to vertical space.